# Valid links in PDF Documents

Tags: software-rec, pdf

I am looking for a application which I can use to check my PDF documents that include links to ensure that they are still up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

"[ARTS PDF Linker](http://www.artspdf.com/arts_pdf_linker.asp) automates the painstaking task of auditing links for validity. All links and bookmarks between documents, to named destinations and to Web pages are examined. ARTS PDF Linker generates several types of CSV and PDF reports, including ones that examine all links and bookmarks, all external dependencies and all bad actions."